# Using IF formula in one sheet and want to keep the value returned when filtering the values from a different sheet

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, filtering

Looking for feedback on a formula I'm using.in
[image: Sheet B]

If it finds a number 1 in column L it returns the value in column A in sheet A.
[image: sheet A]

however When I filter Column L from sheet A my values In sheet B disappear and I want to keep the values even with the filtering.

I appreciate any feedback.

Different formulas with no success

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. The result of the formula on sheet B should be the same regardless of a filter in sheet A ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.